# Cannot include courier into latex beamer listings

Tags: beamer, fonts, formatting, listings, sourcecode

I have the following set up for my listings:

```
\documentclass[russian,pdf]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig, amsmath, mathtools, lmodern, listings, lipsum, courier}

\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.7, 0, 0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0, 0.4, 0}
\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.45, 0, 0.45}
\definecolor{codebg}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}

\lstset{
language=C++,                
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\color{navy},
stringstyle=\color{darkred},
commentstyle=\color{darkgreen},
morecomment=[l][\color{purple}]{\#},
backgroundcolor=\color{codebg},
showspaces=false, 
showstringspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
} 

\begin{document}

\section{C++}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}
    struct employee
    {
        char name [64] ;
        long employee_id;
        float salary;
        char phone[10];
        int office_number;
    };
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And it produces [image]

But I want it to be courier font. What is wrong with my latex source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the beginning of the frame to:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
\begin{lstlisting}
```

If you have to do this for many frames, you can alternatively add these lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}
```

Alternatively, you can compile with `xelatex`, loading the `fontspec` package.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now code looks great, but the \fontencoding{T1}\selectfont conflicts with russian language and I can't add comments in russian to the slides with code. Second option you offered unfortunately doesn't work at all:C

Comment: Do you mean `\AtBeginEnvironment`?

Comment: Yes, \AtBeginEnvironment doesn't change a thing. I found out everything works okay if I switch from T1 to T2A when I need russian and then back again to use listings. Kinda 'dirty' solution, but still fine)

Comment: I had a typo in my initial code: I wrote `\AtBeginEnvironment{listings}` with an *s*. Without an s, it should work. For the problem of comments, perhaps a `begin{russian} … \end{russian}` should do the trick. That said, with xelatex, you don't have to use font encodings, and it should compile smoothly.